# How to get useragent string from default browser?

Tags: c#, browser

is there a working way how to get user's useragent of default browser
from c# console application?
Some solutions which i found are displaying me wrong useragent..
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What do you mean by "default browser"? Are you referring to ASP.NET WebForms' (incredibly ill-thought-out) `.browser` files? If so, you need to know that you shouldn't be using that feature _at all_.

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem. Why do you need to copy another browser's user agent?

Comment: you should get it from the Request object if you have access to it. When you do an http request to a web server you are sending some information as http headers. UserAgent is such an header. Or if you meant something else your question is pretty messed up

Comment: after you edited the question its meaning got darker. I'm afraid you don't have any clue on what useragent means or what default browser means.

Comment: If you want to get an arbitrary implementation detail of an arbitrary piece of software that happens to be installed on the current computer that happens to be configured to be the default handler for URLs (HTTP, HTTPS etc), then no, there is no single universal way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

> is there a working way how to get user's useragent of default browser from c# console application?

No, there isn't.

A user's OS-configured default web-browser could be *anything* (`iexplore.exe`, `chrome.exe`, `lynx.exe`, etc), and they'll all store/represent their `User-Agent` header ([if any...](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/privacy-sandbox/user-agent/)) [differently](https://superuser.com/questions/925817/internet-explorer-editing-user-agent-string-so-it-is-seen-by-the-server), and not in a way that third-party software (i.e. you) can [feasibly](https://github.com/kurtchen/Lynx/search?q=user-agent) obtain.

Comment: You could possibly request a localhost page on a non-standard port using the default browser, then listen to that port. Although I'm not sure how possible / easy that is with the newer cross-platform .NET versions.

Comment: @PeterJ Actually that's a clever out-of-the-box way to do it, I'll admit. But still, no-one should be using the `User-Agent` header today.